# Summing up values contained in sublist under specified condition

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok, so I am trying to get my head around what I feel should be an easy task. I am using Python3.4.

I have the following list that contains sublists (simplified version):

```
newlist = [ ['John', 12],['Mary', 10],['Paul', 12],['Mary', 5],['Paul', 8],['John', 7] ]
```

I am trying to get the sum of all the values that correspond to each unique name. So, in regard to the above-stated list the results should read something like:

John - 19

Mary - 15

Paul - 20

What would be the fastest and/or most efficient way of achieving this?

**Example of my own efforts**

Right now I have solved my problem like so (*but as said: I am looking for a more efficient solution*):

```
unique_names = []
for i in newlist:
    if i[0] not in unique_names:
        unique_names.append(i[0])

valuelist = []
for name in unique_names:
    valuelist.append(name)
    yet_another_list = []
    for i in newlist:
        if name in i:
            yet_another_list.append(i[1])
    valuelist.append(sum(yet_another_list))
```

**EDIT**

**- I tested the answers -**

Ok, so I got a lot of responses, thnx! For the record I tested them by creating separate functions for each of the proposed solutions. I used `start = time.perf_counter()` and `end = time.perf_counter() - start` to calculate the response time of each function. I encapsulated the imports  within each function that required them.

The list I used for this test contained 3985 items / sublists.

The results (rounded to 4 decimals) from 5 different runs where:

my_own_solution: 0.9800 / 0.9703 / 0.9873 / 1.0023 / 0.9540

[defaultdict try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670172/4041795): 0.0014 / 0.0016 / 0.0014 / 0.0018 / 0.0014

[counter try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670201/4041795): 0.0030 / 0.0026 / 0.0026 / 0.0027 / 0.0026

[reduce_try](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670201/4041795): 0.0155 / 0.0153 / 0.0151 / 0.0149 / 0.0174

[ittertry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670510/4041795): 0.0242 / 0.0268 / 0.0239 / 0.0307 / 0.0259 (failed on floats)

[valuelisttry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42670163/4041795): 0.0018 / 0.0018 / 0.0019 / 0.0020 / 0.0043

Overall, I really appreciate the simplicity of the defaultdict statement. This also seems to be the fastest option overall. However, for those in dislike of imports the valuelist (or actually value dictionary) option seems like a fine choice as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict

values = defaultdict(int)

for x, y in newlist:
    values[x]+=y
```

edit: just use defaultdict(int), int already is a callable i didnt think of that!

Comment: `int` already is a callable, so there's no need to wrap it in a `lambda`.

Comment: You should just do `defaultdict(int)`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) object:

```
from collections import Counter

c =  Counter()
for name, cnt in newlist:
    c[name] += cnt

print(c.items())
# [('Paul', 20), ('John', 19), ('Mary', 15)]
```

---

If you're into one liners (although not necessarily more efficient or readable) you can use `functools.reduce` and pass a `Counter` as the initializer:

```
from functools import reduce

c = reduce(lambda x, y: x.update({y[0]: y[1]}) or x, newlist, Counter())
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a defaultdict.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> newlist = [ ['John', 12],['Mary', 10],['Paul', 12],['Mary', 5],['Paul', 8],['John', 7] ]
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for name, score in newlist:
...     d[name] += score
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'Mary': 15, 'John': 19, 'Paul': 20})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
valuelist = {}
for (name, value) in newlist:
  if name not in valuelist:
    valuelist[name] = 0
  valuelist[name] += value

print (valuelist)
```

> {'Paul': 20, 'John': 19, 'Mary': 15}

Answer (score 0):

The fastest approach would probably involve a `Counter` from `collections` and `chain` and `repeat` from `itertools`:

```
from_it = chain.from_iterable
c = Counter(from_it(repeat(i, j) for i,j in chain(newlist)))
```

Which yields:

```
Counter({'John': 19, 'Mary': 15, 'Paul': 20})
```

The statement unpacks every list from `newlist` with `for i,j in chain(newlist)` and then feeds the string `i` (e.g `John`) along with its count `j` to `repeat` in order for it to be repeated that number of times. This comprehension is then passed to `chain.from_iterable` (`from_it`) so it can be supplied as input to `Counter`.